# Alamofire cache response offline. Swift 4

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am new to using Alamofire for swift. I tried reading the documentation, but didn't succeed.

I am making a

```
Alamofire.request("http:json").responseJSON
```

and I discovered, that it works and returns a response even when the phone is offline. If I'm not mistaken, the response is saved in the cache.

How long will this response stay in the cache for the user to use offline?

Should I store the response as a preference?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Alamofire caches your response.
Although, I don't think there's a way to know **when** your response will be dismissed from cache, as there are many variables for the system to consider, for example- disk space... You may use a custom caching policy if you think it's right for you.

I wouldn't count on the default caching policy to save me files for offline usage, and implementing a custom policy feels wrong for that case. So if you really need your files offline, I would recommend you to use a different way.

Take a look on [URLCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcache)- this what Alamofire uses for response caching-

> Response Caching is handled on the system framework level by URLCache. It provides a composite in-memory and on-disk cache and lets you manipulate the sizes of both the in-memory and on-disk portions. -> [From Alamofire documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-caching)